# Which 'commonly-available references' ? Please reopen these 2?

Tags: support

The closer avers that https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184668/imprecate-direct-or-indirect-transitive 'can be answered using commonly-available references.' Can it? I tried but don't see a patent, outright answer. Please reopen?

Please also reopen https://english.stackexchange.com/q/184271/50720? I adduce user Cerberus's instructive comment below: "Examples of prepositions do not claim to be exhaustive, and the Google Books have *against*, which is not mentioned."

**Supplementary to KitFox's answer:** Yet that curt definition doesn't expound on the verb as user Josh61's comment, and doesn't answer 'What prepositions must be used? ?

Answer (score 4):

In the dictionary definition you reference, it says both *with object* and *no object*. That would be the commonly available reference.

It also includes many example sentences that demonstrate acceptable prepositions to use with this word.

Comment: The question is not formulated correctly, but what it wants to know, if you read it carefully, is not properly explained in the dictionary. I would vote to reopen. Examples of prepositions do not claim to be exhaustive, and the Google Books have *against*, which is not mentioned.

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you for your support. Please feel free to emend my OP.

Comment: @Cerb if you edit the question to formulate it in the manner you believe it is intended, I will consider re-opening it.

Comment: @KitFox: I'll leave that to the OP. It is he who wants to know; let him improve it.